# Cordova and Android SDK Manager

Tags: android, cordova

I use Cordova 4.0 and have the android sdk folder in my home and I usually run the `android` command to enter SDK manager:
[image]

I have installed all android sdk versions from 14 (v 4.0) to 22 (v5.1.1) and now that folder is about 45GB.

I'd like to know whether it's really necessary to have all those files installed in order to make my Cordova app working with Android versions from 4.0 to 5.1.1?
So what's the purpose of installing those files from SDK manager?
Are they related to Cordova when doing `cordova build`?

Thanks